Can't call get on my UserProfile model, even when set to allow.guest()
I am having trouble calling "get" on my model. I initially had permissions, but I changed everything to allow.guest() and I still get the Unauthorized error.
Here is my data/resource.ts:
import { type ClientSchema, a, defineData, defineFunction } from '@aws-amplify/backend';
import { AIQuery } from "../functions/AIQuery/resource"
import { postConfirmation } from '../auth/post-confirmation/resource';

const schema = a.schema({
  UserProfile: a
    .model({
      id: a.id().required(),
      email: a.string(),
      subscriptionToken: a.string(),
      profileOwner: a.string(),
    })
    .authorization((allow) => [
      allow.guest()
    ]),
  AIQuery: a
    .query()
    .arguments({
      query: a.string(),
      apiKey: a.string(),
      html: a.string(),
      css: a.string(),
      js: a.string()
    })
    .returns(a.string())
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.guest()])
    .handler(a.handler.function(AIQuery)),
})
.authorization((allow) => [allow.resource(postConfirmation)]);

export type Schema = ClientSchema<typeof schema>;

export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: "userPool",
    lambdaAuthorizationMode: {
      function: defineFunction({
        entry: "./subscription_auth.ts"
      }),
    }
  },
});

And I attempt to access the data like so: 
      let client = generateClient<Schema>({authMode: "userPool"})
client.models.UserProfile.list(client).then((val) => {
                    console.log("val:", val)
                })

I always get Unauthorized error:  Not Authorized to access listUserProfiles on type Query
Any ideas? Is this normal behavior? or could this be a bug? Let me know if there is a config file that I should post to give more information. Thanks
